# Simplifying multiple ints in c

Tags: c, visual-studio, int

I have an assingment to make a program that intakes 14 values, and counts their average value. The values must be between -30 and 40.
I started by initializing all the 14 ints, and started pondering if there's a better way to handle this many values than having all of them individually, especially if making a loop to make sure they are between the required range.

Could and should I make them into some smart struct or something?

Comment: it's called an array.

Comment: don't need an answer for something so easy to mention. you could google this sort of thing. i assume assignment would surely mean prior knowledge :/

Comment: This question can only be read as a request to recommend a basic tutorial and is therefor off-topic. And that is on top of being too broad for containing not enough detail by far.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array. Ex: `int numbers[14]`

You probably want to do a bit more reading about C, either in a book or online.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array of 14 int's.
2. Create a loop to accept 14 values,while each input is added to the sum of the previous input.
3. Divide the answer by 14 when you exit the loop.
4. Print the answer